# Font table with number/name in TeX and spacing, kerning

Tags: fonts

Looking for a way to find out how to call up (May numbers) each character in the font.
I want to print a list of all the glyphs in a font, along with spacing, kerning.
All ligatures, chars etc.

That is:
the letter 'a' = a number/name that I can use in TeX, left spacing, right spacing, kerning

And next make a TeX document with information.

```
    \setfont

    \name-TeX-or-number | name/number | pacing, kerning &
```

Comment: if the font has a `.tfm` file, the program `tftopl` will translate it to "property list" format, which is human readable, if not super-intelligible without a road map.  `texdoc tftopl` for the documentation.  it's not obvious to me that this can be used directly to create a tex document that you can use for reference.

Comment: in xelatex is no .tfm  spacing left, and spacing rigth is different than kerning

Comment: font table not working with xelatex and ttf font

Answer (score 6):

Use `\fonttable`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\section{umranda}
\fonttable{umranda}
\subsection{Usage}
\verb|\font\umranda=umranda \umranda  \char35 --- | \font\umranda=umranda
\umranda  \char35
%
\newpage
\section{umrandb}
\fonttable{umrandb}
\subsection{Usage}
\verb|\font\umrandb=umrandb \umrandb  \char114 --- | \font\umrandb=umrandb
\umrandb  \char114

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fonttable{ptmr7t}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok this is all glyphs but what with space left, and right (in polish odsadzka) spacing, and kerning?

Comment: This is not a answer. This is half answer.

Comment: You table no have ligatures for example 'ff' or 'fi'